# How to add Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.1 for UWP package installer?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, appx, makeappx

I have Xamarin Application. I can build ipa, APK and UWP(.appx) package. ipa and APK is working fine. I am facing issue while installing UWP.

Issue with UWP: It is asking to install `Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.1` as it is one of the dependencies.

Do I need to add `Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.1` in project? If so, where? Can anybody please suggest?

I gave created package with following steps

> 1: Right click UWP project-> Store-> Select create app packages
>
> 2: Now in debug mode we don't need to upload it to the store that's why I
>   select `No`
>
> 3: Than I give path for output location. Give version and select generate app bundle as never and select x86 and x64 architecture as requirement
>
> 4: It generate package

After creating package, user need to install these `Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.1` and `Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00` manually which is given in package folder.

Well, I think this is not ideal case where user need to install the dependencies manually. It should be there in project or it should be install automatically with package as per-requisite.

Let me tell you how we install it. I know there is option to install using PowerShell but I don't have thoroughly idea about it.

> 1- Certificate Installation
>   - MyApp.UWP_1.0.0.0_x86/MyApp.UWP_1.0.0.0_x64.cer
>   - Click on Install Certificate
>   - Select store location as "Local Machine"
>   - Click on Next
>   - It gives you a alert about installation certificate press "Yes"
>   - Than select place all certificate in following store
>   - It enables below textbox with browse option click on browse and select "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"
>   - Click on Next, Finish and Close
>
> 2- Install Dependencies
>   - Open Dependencies --> x86/x64 folder
>   - Install both files
>
> 3- Package Installation
>   - Double click on "MyApp.appx"

Please guide me.

Comment: How are you installing the package? via PowerShell? Can you share the screenshot of the error?

Comment: @Dishant I don't how to install in PowerShell. I have added steps in my question the way we install it. Can you please let me know how to install using powershell? So I can try with it too. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why you are asked to install the dependencies is that your UWP app have a dependency requirement for them but your current Device OS doesn't install these dependencies. If you install your app from the Microsoft Store, the Store will check your app requirments and automatically install the dependencies that your app need but are not installed.

For your issue, you are sideloading your UWP app, since there is no a process as Store to install the dependencies that your app need but are not installed in current device, so you will need to install the dependency manully.

Generally, you can find the dependencies in the **Dependencies** folder from the  corresponding version package's folder (same file path as your appx file). You should install the corresponding dependencies base on your device and the your UWP App appx platform.

**--- Update ---**

If you want to install the app using PowerShell, you still need to install the dependencies. You can use the `Add-AppxPackage` cmdlet to add a signed app package to a user account and use the `DependencyPath` parameter to add all other packages that are required for the installation of the app package. See the topic [Add-AppxPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/add-appxpackage?view=win10-ps#examples) and the [Example 1: Add an app package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/add-appxpackage?view=win10-ps#examples) to install the app and dependencies.

```bsh
PS C:\> Add-AppxPackage -Path "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\MyApp.appx" -DependencyPath "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.1.appx"
```

Comment: Dependencies need to be installed manually by user who is going to install the appx. I just want to skip this manual installation. This is never ideal case where user install dependencies. Usually, dependencies install together with appx installation. Can I set this Dependencies in my project such a way when user install it, dependencies install automatically? Please guide

Comment: Do you have idea about appx installation using PowerShell? I mean if I install using PowerShell, will it install dependencies automatically or still user need to install manually?

Comment: You can use PowerShell to install the app by specifying the package appx file and all dependencies path in your powershell. I have added the Update part in my reply, you can check it.

Comment: Hi! I perform the installation using the same command line as Add-AppxPackage, however the powershell that runs the line uses the local system user. Thus, an error is displayed informing that the user is not allowed to perform this procedure. Negotially, I cannot use a local ADM user to perform this operation. Is there any way to carry out this process using the system?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a .appinstaller file. Creating a .appinstaller file and installing that way will pull in the necessary dependencies. (It works for .appx/.appxbundle and not just .msix/.msixbundle.) See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/how-to-create-appinstaller-file#step-5-add-dependencies).