# Ask the developer for Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.1 package

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to install the .appxbundle file,but it is showing

> App Installer failed to install package dependencies. Ask the developer for Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.1 package.

I downgrade Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform to 6.0.1 then it is asking for

> Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.0 package.

If I updated to latest version 6.2.8 it is asking for

> Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2 package.

Please help me for fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Derive from this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51943455/7254781), your current os miss 
`Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.0 package` dependency. you could get them in the `AppPackages` folder where store the sideload package.

In the `AppPackages` sub folder we could find `Dependencies` folder then chose you want platform folder. You will find Dependencies package like following screenshot.

[image]

You could install them manually.